# A query based on mysql . Would like to know whats wrong in it

Tags: mysql, function, max

whats wrong with this simple query

```
Select max(a) from table;
```

I am not getting the `maximum` value at all. getting something as `9`. but the actual maximum value is `37`.

May this is silly but trying to rectify it . Please help!

Comment: What is the type of `a`?

Comment: where is the query

Comment: `select greatest( '9', '37' ) as max_char, greatest( 9, 37 ) as max_num;` column `a` must be of type `char` if the suggested `select` results to be `9` on column `a`

Comment: the type of a is int .